# How "release" an UIWebView on ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I'm trying to developed a really simple browser to be part of an iPad app. That browser will have tabs. All tabs are based on a .xib with an `UIWebView` filling almost all .xib frame.
I store all them inside an `NSMutableArray`, called `tabsArray`.

So, here's how I add a new tab to the array:
declaration:

.h

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *tabsArray;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIDetailWebController *pagina;
```

.m

```
self.pagina = [[UIDetailWebController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIDetailWebController" bundle:nil];
[tabsArray insertObject:pagina atIndex:currentViewTag+1];
```

how I display it on screen:

```
[self.view addSubview:[[tabsArray objectAtIndex:currentViewTag+1] view]];
```

And, finally, here's how I'm trying to "release" the UIWebView when user closes a tab (with a specific index):

```
[[[tabsArray objectAtIndex:index] view] removeFromSuperview];
[[tabsArray objectAtIndex:index] setWebView:nil];
[[tabsArray objectAtIndex:index] setView:nil];
[tabsArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```

My problem is: It appears that by doing this I simply don't release it. Memory consumption keeps the same, and If I'm playing an youtube video, the audio continues to play.
I'm kind of new on programming, and started iOS development by iOS 5, with ARC, so probably I'm letting slide some basic detail related to memory management.

SOLUTION:

Ok, I found out that what was retaining webview was the implementation of PullToRefreshView (https://github.com/chpwn/PullToRefreshView). When I set it's delegate to nil; everything just works!

Comment: original code was already self.pagina, I just typed it wrong while formating the question. Sorry.

Comment: Are you sure `index` in `[tabsArray objectAtIndex:index]` has the correct value? Also are you sure the code where you remove the view is actually called?

Answer (score 2):

The property `pagina` is is a strong property, so it retains the value that you assign to it in:

```
self.pagina = [[UIDetailWebController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIDetailWebController" bundle:nil];
```

So you should set it to `nil`:

```
[tabsArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
self.pagina = nil; // Add this line.
```

Finally, not that the following lines may not be needed:

```
[[tabsArray objectAtIndex:index] setWebView:nil];
[[tabsArray objectAtIndex:index] setView:nil];
```

And that the line:

```
[[[tabsArray objectAtIndex:index] view] removeFromSuperview];
```

may be simplified into:

```
[self.pagina removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: youtube video keeps playing... :/

Comment: It's not solving. But, it's probably this. My code is extensive, there's lots of different methods to create different types of tabs. Probably I'm forgetting something in the middle. I'll keep looking, If i get it solved, I'll let you know! Thank you! :)

Comment: If instead of the property pagina, I made "UIDetailWebController *pagina = [UIDetailWebController alloc....] I wouldn't need to do anything, right?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you store all your UIDetailWebControllers in an array. The array is keeping a strong pointer to your DetailWebController.
You should use:

```
[tabsArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```

And then set

```
self.pagina = nil;
```

After calling `[self.pagina removeFromSuperView];` it should work.

Comment: Not solving it. But setting self.pagina to nil realy seams to be the solution. If I choose to instead of make it a property, I just UIDetailWebController *pagina, I wouldn't need to do anything else to release the webview, right?